# Chevron icon is not going to downward after going up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle a chevron-icon, but nothing happen.

```
$("span:last").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
```

If I added this code below slidetoggle without `if else` section, then the icon change to up but not to down again .

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">       </script>
//starting jquery
<script>

$("#header").ready(function(){
    $("#logo").hide();
    $("#header").click(function(){
    $("#logo").slideToggle("slow");

});


$("#down").click(function() {

    var $changeicon= $("down");

    if ($changeicon .hasclass("glyphicon-chevron-down")) {

        $changeicon.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
    }
    else {
        $changeicon.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");

    } 
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<button type ="button" class ="btn btn-success btn-lg" id ="header">
        <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-home pull-left">    <strong>Header</strong>       </span><span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right btn-small" id ="down"> </span></button>
<div class ="row">
         <div class ="col-lg-12" >
            <p id ="logo" style="background-color:#D9D9D9;">  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Logo</a><br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Skype</a></p>

            </div> </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hint: `$changeicon.toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-up glyphicon-chevron-down')`

Comment: i put this in the code but still icon not toggling.

Comment: It was a hint. It wasn't supposed to fix your issue, otherwise I'd have posted it as an answer. You can use `.toggleClass()` instead of your big if statement.

Comment: I can't imagine jQuery likes `$changeicon .hasclass("glyphicon-chevron-down")` very much. You should really, really learn to use your JS console window when you run into issues. Everything that people have posted is irrelevant until you fix this.

Comment: hmmmmmmmm thanks. but problem is not solved.

Comment: I never said this would solve all of your problems and I'm very sad to learn that you have no passion for what you are doing.

Comment: "hmmmmmmmm thanks. but problem is not solved." hmm thanks but i said this to george.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to work you need to change the following:

- jquery click selector -> change `$("#down").click(function()` to `$("#header").click(function()`
- the element with id="down" has no size -> to correct this change var `$changeicon= $("down");` to `$changeicon= $(this).find("#down");`
- Capital "C" letter in class -> `$changeicon .hasclass("glyphicon-chevron-down")` needs to be `$changeicon.hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-down")`

Check working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f9kxm1wg/)

PS. Learn how to use the browsers' debugger tools ... they're very useful and can save you a lot of time waiting for someone like me to solve your syntax mistakes.

Comment: its working ...thanks @henser and all others for help.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
var $changeicon= $("down");
```

to this:

```
var $changeicon= $("#down");
```

You've just forget a `#` sign, and there will be nothing in `$changeicon`.

Update:

You have also a missing: `});` to close the header ready section.

So the jQuery should like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#header").ready(function() {
        $("#logo").hide();
        $("#header").click(function() {
            $("#logo").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    $("#down").click(function() {
        var $changeicon = $("#down");
        if ($changeicon.hasclass("glyphicon-chevron-down")) {

            $changeicon.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
        }
        else {
            $changeicon.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: see my updated answer. You have another syntax error. When developing javascript, use console to check errors.

Comment: still i am very confused,, can u tell me the complete code which i just put in my script section. i put above code in my script section but chevron icon is not changing.

Comment: this is the whole code, what is in my answer. IT should work now.

Comment: icon is not changing, logo id id toggling, and i want to toggle icon.

Comment: using this code my icon is changing but then not move to downward.$("#header").ready(function(){
$("#logo").hide();
  $("#header").click(function(){
    $("#logo").slideToggle("slow");
 $("span:last").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
});